# Bug in tag privileges

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, privileges, edits

I have access to edit tag wikis even though I do not have the 20k required to attain the privledge or the required bronze tag.

A tag wiki I created: [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd), yet I only currently have 19765 rep, do not have the bronze in that tag, and am shown on the privileges page as not having the privilege.

Comment: Did it show you a comment at the top "You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed."

Comment: Nope.  It did not show any warning (which is why I tried).  I can get to the edit page on every tag I tried (even those I have no answers for)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch ... will be deploying a fix later on